# What is the difference between sequential consistency and acquire/release semantics?

Tags: c++, multithreading, lock-free, memory-barriers, stdatomic

As far as I know, acquire/release semantics act as a middle ground between sequential consistency and the unconditional memory reordering freedom allowed by a weaker memory model (or "relaxed", as C++ calls it). In a nutshell:

- Acquire semantics prevent memory reordering of a `read` with any `read` or `write` operation that follows it in program order;
- Release semantics prevent memory reordering of a `write` with any `read` or `write` operation that precedes it in program order.

Cool. But those guarantees, combined together, look like sequential consistency to me. What does sequential consistency provide that acquire/release semantics together don't? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

In hardware terms, acq/rel allows a store/reload within one thread to store-forward the value from the store buffer before it becomes *globally* visible to other threads.

seq_cst forces the store buffer to drain before a seq-cst load can reload a seq-cst store from the same thread.

This is the difference for https://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/ - adding a full memory barrier between the store and reload is what's needed (on x86) to go from acq_rel to seq_cst.

Comment: See my answer on the linked duplicate, [How do memory\_order\_seq\_cst and memory\_order\_acq\_rel differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58043923), for a more detailed version, including how AArch64 is about as weak as the standard allows, so SC stores can reorder with later operations except for SC loads.  Also IRIW reordering.

Answer (score 2):

What is extra is the single total modification order: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Sequentially-consistent_ordering